# Class not found when unmarshalling in PreferenceFragment

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment, preferences

I try to implement a day/night system changeable directly from the settings. I used PreferenceFragmentCompat for this but however, when I press the switch preference to change the mode. I have the following error:

```
E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

I looked everywhere but I don't really understand where the error comes from..

---

This is my Preference Activity:

```
public class PreferencesActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_preferences);

        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

        if (savedInstanceState == null)
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.preferences_container, new PreferencesFragment()).commit();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        if(key.contains(getString(R.string.KEY_PREF_NIGHT_MODE)))
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false)? AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES: AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
    }


    public static class PreferencesFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey);
        }

    }

}
```

And I use this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/noteRecyclerBackground"
    tools:context=".PreferencesActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/preferences_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Which specific line does it crash on and did you check your imports? Make sure you're not mixing `androidx` classes with framework or support lib classes.

Comment: There is no crash but an error and this is when the activity restart with `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false)? AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES: AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);`

Answer (score 0):

> There is no crash but an error and this is when the activity restart with AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false)? AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES: AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);

Well, [per the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatDelegate#setDefaultNightMode(int)), this sounds like expected behavior.

> If this method is called after any host components with attached AppCompatDelegates have been 'created', a uiMode configuration change will occur in each. **This may result in those components being recreated, depending on their manifest configuration**.

Comment: I don't know, but if the error is not causing you a problem and the restart is expected, why not just ignore it and move on?